# Node.js / Express get adding route declaratively

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, declarative

I'm trying to manage my routes in declarative objects and then initialize/register the endpoint handlers using one or more of the objects.

Unfortunately, when I try to register the handlers in a loop of the declarative routes, methods, and handlers, the routes do not seem to be registered with Express and result in 404's when I try to access the routes.

Here is a code snippet:

```
const services = require('./services.js');

const appRoutes = [
  { route: '/x/user', handler: { get: services.getUserName, post: services.getUserName } },
  { route: '/x/ping', handler: { get: services.ping } },
  { route: '/x/mary/had/:foo/little/:animal', handler: { get: (req, res) => res.send({ foo: req.params.foo, animal: req.params.animal }) } }
];

class routes {
  static registerRoutes(app, rs) {
    rs.forEach(r => {
      const rt = r.route;
      const h = r.handler;
      console.log('registerRoutes.routes.forEach: ' + rt + '; hs: ' + h.get);
      if (h.get) app.get(rt, h.get);
      if (h.post) app.post(rt, h.post);
      if (h.delete) app.delete(rt, h.delete);
      if (h.head) app.head(rt, h.head);
      if (h.put) app.put(rt, h.put);
    });
  }
  static initializeRoutes(app) {
    this.initializeDevRoutes(app);
  }
  static initializeDevRoutes(app) {
    const rs = [
      { route: '/z/user', handler: { get: services.getUserName, post: services.getUserName } },
      { route: '/z/ping', handler: { get: (req, res) => res.send('pinged') } }
    ];
    this.registerRoutes(app, appRoutes);
    this.registerRoutes(app, rs);
    app.get('/api/getUsername', services.getUserName); // (req, res) => res.send({ username: os.userInfo().username }));
    app.get('/api/ping', services.ping); // (req, res) => res.send({ ping: new Date() }));
    app.get('/api/mary/had/:foo/little/:animal', (req, res) => res.send({ food: req.params.foo, animal: req.params.animal }));
  }
}

module.exports = routes;
```

The `/x/...` or `/z/...` routes are not being successfully registered since I get 404's for all of those routes.

However, for the explicit calls to `app.get('/api/....)` at the bottom do register the routes correctly since the expected 200 status results are returned.

This is my first node/js project so I might be missing something in how JS scopes and handling closures.

Any help/suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Think some very basic debugging will solve this, there's nothing obvious from the code...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I started the dev server using: `npm run dev`.

The browser opened automatically to the dev server (running on port 3000) that only proxied for `/api` to the actual server (running on port 8080) (inside the `webpack.config.js` file under `devServer`).  The routes work as expected when hitting the actual server running on port 8080.